# 5125cc8e register_matching_rule: could not locate associated matching rule generalizedTimeMatch

Tags: openldap

After compiling openldap-2.4.33 on Centos 6.3 with the following options, I am unable to understand what this error is telling me:

Server was installed as a 'minimal' install, with the following addons:

```
yum install ntp autofs gcc make perl strace nmap tree rpm-build rpm-devel rpmdevtools rpm-libs rpm-python \
openssl openssl-devel perl-CPAN libtool libtool-ltdl-devel.x86_64 libtool-ltdl.x86_64 \
db4.x86_64 nss_db.x86_64 compat-db.x86_64 db4-devel.x86_64 \
tcp_wrappers.x86_64 tcp_wrappers-devel.x86_64 tcp_wrappers-libs.x86_64 \
unixODBC unixODBC-devel mysql-devel cyrus-sasl-devel.x86_64 perl-ExtUtils-Embed.x86_64 \
-y
```

After basic installation of the server as a VM on ESX, I ran the following ./configure to compile and install :

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I /usr/lib64/perl5/CORE" 
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE"
export PERL_CPPFLAGS="`perl -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE`"
ldconfig
./configure \
--prefix=/ \
--enable-shared   --enable-debug   --enable-dynamic         --enable-syslog      --enable-proctitle  --enable-ipv6   \
--enable-local    --enable-slapd   --enable-cleartext       --enable-crypt       --enable-lmpasswd   --enable-spasswd  \
--enable-modules  --enable-rewrite --enable-rlookups        --enable-slapi       --enable-slp        --enable-wrappers  \
--enable-backends --enable-bdb     --enable-dnssrv          --enable-hdb         --enable-ldap       --enable-mdb  \
--enable-meta     --enable-monitor --enable-null            --enable-passwd      --enable-perl       --enable-relay    \
--enable-shell    --enable-sock    --enable-sql             --enable-overlays    --enable-accesslog  --enable-auditlog  \
--enable-collect  --enable-constraint  --enable-dds         --enable-deref       --enable-dyngroup   --enable-dynlist  \
--enable-memberof --enable-ppolicy     --enable-proxycache  --enable-refint      --enable-retcode    --enable-rwm         \
--enable-seqmod   --enable-sssvlv      --enable-syncprov    --enable-translucent --enable-unique     --enable-valsort      \
--enable-perl     --disable-ndb        --with-cyrus-sasl    --with-threads       --with-tls          --with-yielding-select  \
```

--with-mp

I've taken the basic slapd.conf and only added my own dn.

When I run slaptest this is what I get:

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/
5125cefd register_matching_rule: could not locate associated matching rule generalizedTimeMatch for ( 2.5.13.28 NAME 'generalizedTimeOrderingMatch' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24 )
slap_schema_init: Error registering matching rule ( 2.5.13.28 NAME 'generalizedTimeOrderingMatch' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.24 )
5125cefd slaptest: slap_schema_init failed
```

The only schema with some kind of clue is ppolicy.schema, but I'm at a loss as to what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Those *matching rules* are internal, both are defined in OpenLDAP's `servers/slapd/schema_init.c` with no conditionals.
`generalizedTimeMatch` is defined first, and then `generalizedTimeOrderingMatch`, which refers to `generalizedTimeMatch` in its "associated" matching rule. The error originates in `servers/slapd/mr.c` as the matching rules are added.

The matching rules are built in an array of `struct slap_mrule_defs_rec`, and iterated over in order. There's no obvious way for that to fail.

Your list of options and overlays is quite, um, complete.
There is a chance that there's some incompatibility or dependency problem with the overlays, but I don't see it (several overlays add to the schema and *use* those matching rules as a side-effect of some attributes: `dds`, `ppolicy`, `accesslog`; as does the `monitor` backend).

My best guess is that there is some compile problem, possibly arising from compiler options, either optimisation/alignment and/or some stale `.o` file, but I'm guessing here. You don't include your actual make and install steps, there's a similarly slim chance that you have some conflict arising from an incomplete installation, or previous installation (old binaries or schema files).

I'd suggest:

```
make clean
make depend && make && make test
```

and see what happens (`make test` will take quite some time). It that works, then you might consider installing to `/usr/local` to avoid conflicting files. If that doesn't work then try a simple `configure` with minimal options:

```
./configure --with-threads --with-tls
```

and then add in *just* the modules and backend(s) you need.

Comment: Your hint is where it got me fixed on this issue, at least for me, based on http://www.openldap.org/its/index.cgi/Incoming?id=8278;page=113;statetype=-1 I had to disable SLP and it got me past the slaptest